Probability problem with binomial series
everyone. I'm studying probability and a question says:
"Suppose N a discrete random variable with probability function:
$$P(N = n) = 0,5^{n+1},$$ for n $\in$ {0,1,2,...}
and another discrete random variable that follow the conditional distribution
$$P(X = x|N = n) = \binom{n}{x}0,5^n$$
for $0 \leq x \leq n$.
The variance of X is equal to 7,5. True of False?"
I used the formula $$P(X=x|N=n) = \frac{P(X=x,N=n)}{P(N=n)}$$
and i found
$$P(X=x,N=n) = \binom{n}{x}(0,5)^{2n+1}$$
I know that i can sum in N to find the marginal funcion of X, that is
$$P(X = x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{x}0,5^{2n+1}$$
for $0 \leq x \leq n$
but i can't solve this series. Am i doing something wrong i didn't see?

The problem isn't to find a closed form for a series: it's to compute a variance.  See the Law of Total Variance for one approach.  Nevertheless, the series has a simple closed formula: use the Binomial theorem and the sum of the geometric series.

@whuber Thank you so much!
